# How to use ipdb to debug a jupyter notebook containing ipywidgets in VS code

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, ipywidgets

```
from ipywidgets import widgets
import ipdb

# Create a DatePicker widget
dp = widgets.DatePicker(
    description='Pick a Date',
    disabled=False
)

# Display the widget
display(dp)

# A button to signal completion of date selection
button = widgets.Button(description="I'm done picking a date")
display(button)

def on_button_clicked(b):
    ipdb.set_trace()
    print(f'Date selected: {dp.value}')

button.on_click(on_button_clicked)
```

I'm attempting to debug the above code in a jupyter notebook in VS Code.

I am expecting the debugger to stop at the line containing `ipdb.set_trace()` after I press the "I'm done picking a date" button .  However, after I press the button the code stops running and the output produced is below[image]